# How to make IDE such as ATOM relate to template HTML in javascript string as HTML?

Tags: html, templates, ide, atom-editor, vuejs2

I'm writing with Vue 2 components which include html templates:

```
Vue.component('my-component', {

template: `
<div id="myDiv">
</div>
`

}
```

I need Atom (or any IDE) to recognize that the text in the "template" property is, in fact, HTML.
I want Atom to respond properly with HTML snippets and auto indenting this text as HTML.

Does this feature have a name? 
And is it possible in Atom IDE ?

Comment: Atom has a large library of plugins; have you looked for Vue-related plugins that support this?

Comment: I installed the most popular plugin for Vue, but I need to know the name of this feature so I could look for it specifically.

Comment: @Zephram try language-vue plugiiin for atom....

Comment: Thanks ! I will !

Answer (score 0):

In Atom: Settings -> Install Packages -> **language-babel**

(this only shows **code highlighting**, doesn't make indentation)